# Unable to join Fedora 20 machine to Active Directory RODC with realmd

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, fedora

I don't know a lot about Active Directory, but I have some basic knowledge of what it does. I have been trying to join a Fedora 20 machine to the domain, and have been having some issues. I ran the `realm` command as such:

```
sudo realm join -v -U [admin user] [hostname of RODC]
```

For some reason, I have to use the host name of the read-only domain controller. If I use the name of the domain, I get the following error:

```
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.[domain]
 ! Discovery timed out after 15 seconds
```

If I specify the host name of the RODC, all goes well: It resolves, asks for the password of the admin user specified in the command, authenticates, but fails when setting the password for the computer account:

```
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.[RODC host name]
 * Resolving: [RODC host name]
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: [internal IP of RODC]
 * Successfully discovered: [domain]
Password for [domain admin]: 
 * Required files: /usr/sbin/oddjobd, /usr/libexec/oddjob/mkhomedir, /usr/sbin/sssd, /usr/sbin/adcli
 * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain [domain] --domain-realm [domain, in caps] --domain-controller [internal IP of RODC] --login-type user --login-user [domain admin] --stdin-password
 * Using domain name: [domain]
 * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: [machine host name, in caps/computer account]
 * Using domain realm: [domain]
 * Sending cldap pings to domain controller: [internal IP of RODC]
 * Received NetLogon info from: [host name of RODC, in caps].[domain]
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-pMXPuH/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-OcXLS5
 * Authenticated as user: [admin user]@[domain, in caps]
 * Looked up short domain name: [short name]
 * Using fully qualified name: [machine host name].[domain]
 * Using domain name: [domain name]
 * Using computer account name: [computer account]
 * Using domain realm: [domain name]
 * Enrolling computer account name calculated from fqdn: [computer account]
 * Generated 120 character computer password
 * Using keytab: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
 * Using fully qualified name: [machine host name].[domain]
 * Using domain name: [domain]
 * Using computer account name: [computer account]
 * Using domain realm: [domain]
 * Looked up short domain name: [short name]
 * Found computer account for [computer account]$ at: CN=[computer account],OU=[redacted] Computers,OU=[redacted],OU=[redacted],OU=[redacted],DC=[redacted],DC=[redacted],DC=[redacted]
 ! Couldn't set password for computer account: [computer account]$: Incorrect net address
adcli: joining domain [domain] failed: Couldn't set password for computer account: [computer account]$: Incorrect net address
 ! Failed to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Failed to join the domain
```

Doing some searching, I found a [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463167.aspx) that mentions the "incorrect net address" error as a DNS issue. Where should I look first to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Your basic problem is that Active Directory is very DNS-dependant, particularly that you need to be able to resolve the domain in order to join a client to it, regardless of the client OS. Therefore, your inability to resolve the domain itself when using the `realmd` command is going to be a show-stopper. That's where you need to direct your troubleshooting efforts, and the problem you need to resolve before you'll be able to proceed. My first step would be to set the client's network configuration to use the local domain controller(s) for DNS, manually if necessary, and see what that gets me.

Comment: DHCP already sets the DNS servers to the IP addresses to the 2 RODC's on our local network.

Comment: Well, that's a curious rub.  Ultimately, though, you still need to figure out why you can't resolve the domain (or `realmd` can't resolve the domain), because that's what's causing the problem.  Your DNS servers being set to the local RODC makes that problem all the more confusing and perplexing, but that's the problem you need to figure out.

Comment: What would you recommend for troubleshooting? I've done an nslookup on the domain, and it returns 4 different IP address. I'm not sure what to make of this.

Comment: I don't really know what to suggest in the way of troubleshooting, but the nslookup returning 4 IP addresses is expected.  Those IPs would correspond to the 4 Domain Controllers defined as the domain in the DNS records.  I guess my next step would be to make sure all the IPs you get back from an nslookup are reachable and have proper hostnames in the reverse lookup zones.  (which you can ascertain by doing an nslookup against the IPs, and trying to connect to the hostnames you get back).

Comment: Doing a reverse lookup on the IP's returns a host name. I must wonder though why none of the Windows computers have any issues joining. My only experience of joining a computer to the domain is running and executable (OfflineJoin) and logging out.

Comment: The machine I am attempting to join dual-boots Windows 8 with Fedora. I've found that I can ping the domain name in Windows, but can't under Fedora. The DNS and other network settings are the same. What could cause this?

Comment: ... no idea.  Sorry.

Comment: Since you said that you can resolve domain.com from a Windows machine, but not from the Linux machine, assuming the two clients are using the same DNS server, that would imply that the two clients are not sending the same DNS query. Working versus broken network packet captures would gain you further insight here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are seeing this error is because you can't write to the RODC to create a password. AD creates a computer password when the object is created and a randomly generated one while joining a domain.

You have to rely on Kerberos which caches the server password and when you join to RODC it will not prompt you. First create a keytab file on the writable DC for the specific Linux server then move it there, preferable to `/etc/krb5.keytab` and set permission to 600.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to create anything on a and Active Directory RODC.  The RO part stands for Read Only.  Work with your Active Directory administrators to get the hostname of a writable domain controller.

Comment: For security reasons the writable DC is protected and you may only have access to the RODC.